# Django (?P<pk>\d+) in URL's partly working

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have this as my **users app urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from users import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.UserListView.as_view(),name='user_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.UserProfileView.as_view(),name='user_profile'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit$',views.UserEditProfileView.as_view(),name='user-profile-edit'),
    url(r'^login/$',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',views.user_logout,name='user_logout'),
    url(r'^register/$',views.register,name='register'),
]
```

This url pattern `url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.UserProfileView.as_view(),name='user_profile'),`

works with this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/1/`

But when I made a new user (user 2) and logged in I get a `page not found (404)` when I click on the button that goes with that pattern

The are not errors but this is what it tells me:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/3/
Raised by:  users.views.UserProfileView
No user profile info found matching the query
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

So basically it the profile for user with the pk 3 is at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/2/` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/3/` (or the other way around, not really sure).

Also here are my **project urls:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from users import views
from feed import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.HomeView.as_view(),name='index'),
    url(r'^user/',include('users.urls',namespace='users')),
    url(r'^feed/',include('feed.urls',namespace='feed')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**users app views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from users.forms import UserForm,UserProfileForm
from users.models import UserProfileInfo
from feed.models import UserPost

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account now active")

        else:
            print("Login Unsuccessful")
            return HttpResponse("Username and/or password are not correct")

    else:
        return render(request,'login.html',{})

def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(request,'register.html',{
                                        'user_form':user_form,
                                        'profile_form':profile_form,
                                        'registered':registered
                                        })

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

class UserListView(ListView):
    model = UserProfileInfo
    ordering = ['-join_date']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_list'] = User.objects.all()
        return context

class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    model = UserProfileInfo
    template = 'users/userprofile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_post'] = UserPost.objects.all()
        return context

class UserEditProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = '/users_detail.html'
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    model = UserProfileInfo
```

**users app models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.choices import *

# Create your models here.
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='User')
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,default=1)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500,default='about')
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    dribbble = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    github = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

UPDATE:

New user app models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='User')
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,default=1)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500,default='about')
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    dribbble = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    github = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.userprofile.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

New Error:

```
IntegrityError at /user/register/
UNIQUE constraint failed: users_userprofile.user_id
```

Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users_userprofile.user_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/garrettlove/Desktop/evverest/users/views.py", line 58, in register
    profile.save()
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 807, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 837, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 923, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 962, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1076, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users_userprofile.user_id
```

Comment: Please add `views.py` and also `models.py` your url is **correct** you just need to modify the  `UserProfileView`

Comment: @AstikAnand just added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you have done is correct. But **error is self explanatory**. Your `UserProfileInfo` is **one-to-one** related to `User` Model. So once you create a new user. A new userprofileinfo is to be created but that is not getting created automatically. Hence it is giving error.

> You need to send a signal to create a new userprofileinfo whenever a new user is created.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='User')
    . . . . . . . . 
    . . . . . . . .

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userprofile.save()
```

Lastly, I have changed the model name, so change it accordingly. Now, it will work perfectly.

Comment: @Garret, Have you tried this solution?? Did it worked for you?

Comment: I think I implemented in correctly, but I'm getting this error: `IntegrityError at /user/register/
UNIQUE constraint failed: users_userprofileinfo.user_id`

Comment: I told you that I have changed the model name from `UserProfileInfo` to `UserProfile` keep that in check.

Comment: from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
 ##Model fields here
 @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
 def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
   UserProfileInfo.objects.create(user=instance)

 @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
 def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  instance.userprofileinfo.save()
 
 def __str__(self):
  return self.user.username`

Comment: I'm pretty I did change the models in my last comment? I changed your `UserProfile` to `UserProfileInfo`. was that not what you meant?

Comment: I meant change your `UserProfileInfo` to  mine `UserProfile` and not the reverse.

Comment: I changed it in the model as well as everywhere else in the project that pointed to that model and it still gives me that integrity error. I will update the post to the the exact code I am using in the model and the traceback to the error.

Comment: Can you give me your `Teamviewr Id` so that I can see the code and correct it??

Comment: 103 225 143 I think that's it, never used team viewer before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154036/discussion-between-astik-anand-and-garrett).

Answer (score 1):

Your `urls.py` is wrong. whenever you're calling `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/3/` it calls the view `users.views.UserProfileView`, and this `UserProfileView` is not getting any `userID` which you need to pass in `urls.py`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.HomeView.as_view(),name='index'),
    url(r'^user/(?P<pk>\d+)/',include('users.urls',namespace='users')),
    url(r'^feed/',include('feed.urls',namespace='feed')),
]
```

Comment: The `url` is correct, modification needs to be done in `views.py`.

Comment: pretty sure I am passing in the `userID` in my template here: `<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user_profile' user.id %}">` sorry i didn't put that in the post.

Comment: It's a generic view for the `UserProfileInfo` model. So you need to pass that pk to `{% url %}`, not the pk for `User`. `<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user_profile' user.user_profile_info.id %}">`

Comment: Also make sure that a `UserProfileInfo` exists for the `User`, as explained by @AstikAnand

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the url be:

```
url(r'^user/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.UserProfileView.as_view(), name='user_profile'),
```

Comment: I don't think so because I include this file in my project urls. sorry I just edited the post to show that.

Comment: @Garrett Can you checkin database if the profile for user 3 exists? You shall also write logic in code to create userprofile if it doesn't exists.